# Is Urn of Shadows affected by Magic Resistance?

Tags: dota-2, dota

It's relevant to Maledict, I need to find out whether the damage from Urn is flat HP loss (true/pure damage or if it's reduced by 25% or more.

Thanks. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Urn of Shadows deals damage as HP removal and thus is not affected by resistance.

http://www.dota2wiki.com/wiki/Urn

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Urn of Shadows was changed from magic to pure damage in v6.69, with no changes to its nuke in later versions.

[6.69 Changelog](http://www.playdota.com/changelogs/6.69)

Comment: That's unclear, it actually makes me think that it deals magic damage because it specifically says that the DPS remains unchanged.

Comment: I found a couple of discussions regarding the urn that say it's no longer reduced by magic resistance/items such as Hood/Pipe, you can probably test this easily yourself with an AI map, setting it to -emntnbom, and buying the Urn right away.